# VNC client with GUI that can connect to a VNC server through an SSH tunnel

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I am looking for a VNC client with a GUI that can connect to VNC server through an SSH tunnel. It should work on Microsoft Windows. Any license and price is fine.

RealVNC client does not have SSH:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may try this one:

[Enhanced TightVNC Viewer](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/ssvnc.html)